# why does command window opens then close then open another window

Tags: windows, command

I know this question looks like dozen of others: but, I am trying to get insight into why this script acts the way it does and if there is any draw back to it like memory leak or other.

The script its simple:
`cd "C:\me\python\.venv" && start C:\me\python\.venv\env\Scripts\activate`

There is a windows that opens briefly then closes then another command window opens with the virtual environment open as I need. This question is not about the virtual environment in any way. I am trying to understand the command window.

It seems buggy that a command window opens to change directories then closes and then another opens the virtual environment in another window. I can live with this I guess until I run across a seemless way to do this; but, isn't there a better way to do this?

Is the window opening then closing the behavior of the command prompt when changing directories? No! The script could be written simply as:
`start C:\me\python\.venv\env\Scripts\activate`
and there is still an occurence of a window opening prior to the window with the virtual environment started.

Is there any after affects from doing it this way, like background process open or memory leak or what have you?

Anyone know where to read the "readme" on this behavior?

Thank you much!

Comment: I think what I am seeing is the result of two scripts involved. There is the script spelled out in the post above that calls a second script, the ```activate.bat``` script; and, so, the first window opens as a result of the first script which calls the second and then it close just prior to the second script opening.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
cd "C:\me\python\.venv" && C:\me\python\.venv\env\Scripts\activate
```

the `start` command is not necessary and that's what opens one more window and lets the previous one close.
This command create a new windows asynchronously.

Comment: without the ```start``` command the window does not stay open for me.
Can you clarify that you have different results?

I try without ```start``` but the window does not stay open and yet still it looks as if it flashes open twice.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of the scripts you run?

Comment: The script is as reads in op. The requirements are to have python installed and set-up with virtual venv. The last id in the path is activate.bat which is the second half of the script in the op.

I am not asking you to set-up these requirements especially if you have to go out of your way. I was thinking that any call to a second script would show the same behaviour with an instance of the command window flash opening.

Soon, I will test by replacing the call to activate a python venv with a call to a pure windows batch file. I will let you know then what I see. Thanks for you time!

Comment: you could try to create a "link" that sets the execution directory and then you can use with `start "" /wait ...` or without `start` to see the result. Also you can run a bacth file hidden or with the window minimized. Also consider the /B parameter which does not create the new window in the `start` command